# Wordpress How to query across multiple post types with meta queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've got three fairly complicated queries I'm stuck on.  First, I have two custom post types : One for Departments, and one for Employees.  Within Employees there are various positions/fields (labeled 'additional roles') you can choose for each employee, but the two I need are 'Staff' and 'Library'.

The first query I need is all Employees who either belong to any Department, are Employees who are staff, or Employees who are library.  Some employees are only one, or combinations of all three.

The next two are a bit simpler.  I one query only for Employees who are only staff (do not belong to a department), or only library (also do not belong to a department).

I've been writing and re-writing these queries and am not making any progress.  I think there are SQL commands needed that I can't figure out.  I'll share what my latest iterations are.

For the first query (employees in department, staff, or library):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => '-1',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'last_name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'additional_roles',
            'value'   => array('staff', 'library'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The second (only staff)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_key' => 'additional_roles',
    'meta_value' => 'staff',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The query for library is the same as the staff, only meta_value is 'library'.  I know the first shouldn't work because it's not connected to the Department cpt, but not sure how to do that.  But I'm not sure why the other two aren't working.  Currently I'm not getting ANY posts returning.

I hope I've explained this well enough.  I'm happy to share more if needed.  Thank you!

Comment: how are you adding them to department?

Comment: @Moishy They are being added via Post Object field in the Employee CPT

Comment: whats that field called?

Comment: It's called Department

Answer (score 0):

`posts_per_page` is an `INT` (youre providing a string)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'last_name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'additional_roles',
            'value'   => array('staff', 'library'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'department',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$first_query = new WP_Query($args);

$staff_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'additional_roles',
    'meta_value' => 'staff',
);
$staff_query = new WP_Query($staff_args);

$library_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'additional_roles',
    'meta_value' => 'library',
);
$library_query = new WP_Query($library_args);
```

I havent tested this code. Let me know if this helps

Comment: also not sure if you intended on the first query you are also checking for `meta_key` last_name

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either

Comment: I'm curious about the department key in the meta query.  Department is another custom post type, does it belong as part of the meta query?  My understanding was that it only pertains to custom fields.

Comment: you mentioned it was an ACF field pulling the CPT

Comment: try removing `meta_key => 'last_name'`

Comment: Oh, right.  I tried removing that and still no results.

Comment: are you getting results without the meta query?

Comment: Yes, without the meta query it retrieves all employees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250380/discussion-between-rrhodes-and-moishy).